# Entity is saved after form submit without being persisted

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have a Form with 3 Layers.

The built in validation is somehow not triggered through all 3 levels. Therefore I have to check manually for Errors on the third level. If I find an error, the entity with the error is not persisted. A flush is always triggered at the end of the loop. Unfortunately even without being persisted, some invalid entities are saved in the database. Here is my Controller for it:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new GameListType(), $betRound);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        $betRound = $form->getData();
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($betRound->getGames() as $game) {
                if ($game->hasBet()) {
                    $bet = $game->getBet();
                    // Filter are used during select
                    // , but dont work for inserts
                    // should work in this current context!
                    $bet->setGame($game);
                    $bet->setBetRound($betRound);
                    $bet->setUser($user);

                    $validator = $this->container->get('validator');
                    $errors = $validator->validate($bet);
                    if (count($errors) == 0) {
                        print($bet. ' got persisted'); <-- never triggered
                        $em->persist($bet);
                    } else {
                        // Manual Error Handling 
                        // (no cascade Validation to third level
                        foreach ($errors as $violation) {
                            $form->addError(new FormError(
                                                    $violation->getMessageTemplate(),
                                                    $violation->getMessageParameters(),
                                                    $violation->getMessagePluralization()
                                    ));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } // foreach ($betRound->getGames() as $game)
            $em->flush();

            if(!$form->hasErrors()){
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('betround_show', 
                        array('id' => $betRound->getId())
                        ));
            }
        }
```

The persist operation is never triggered, but the invalid $bet entities are still saved in the database.

Comment: Do you have any LifeCycleArgs that may be doing it for you?

Comment: Not that i know of, there are some that would add modifications to the bet entity after persisting, but I still don't know where the bet gets persisted in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if you have a cascade option on the relation between game and bet.

Is it really persist that is the problem or is it update?  Are the bets already existing and you just don't want to update your changes if the validation fails?  If so, what you need to do is to undo the changes when validation fails with $em->refresh($bet);

Comment: In this case it is an update I want to prevent. Why is the cascade option relevant? Im not cascading my game entity either. I will Try the refresh, but I still dont know, why the bet gets in the changeset in the first place.

Comment: It gets changed because you are changing it with $bet->setGame().  Likewise, if the bet shows up on the form then $form->bind will change it as well.  The refresh will reload the original bet from the database and should take care of the problem.

Comment: You could also use a deferred explicit change tracking policy.  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html which requires you to persist any object that you want updated.  But you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used the refresh, as it seemed for me the easiest solution.